# Eliminating Space using Mathematical or Probability Equation

Tags: geometry

Let us say that there are one transmitter and two receivers. The receivers R1 is located at $(-c,0)$ and R2 is located at $(c,0)$ while the transmitter is located at $(x,y)$ (All in Cartesian Plane). I want to eliminate some quadrants from Cartesian plane when I have the time difference of signal arrival. For example if the transmitter is located at Q1, I should be able to eliminate Q2 and Q3 as the possible location of transmitter because the time arrival of R2 is lower than R1.

I just don't know how to write it in mathematical formula or probabilistic equation. Any help please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The set of points in the plane that are closer to $R_2$ than to $R_1$ is given by the condition $x > 0$; similarly, the points that are closer to $R_1$ than $R_2$ is given by $x < 0$, and the $y$-axis, or $x = 0$, is the locus of points that are equidistant from the two receivers.  Since the converse is true, based on the observed signal arrival times, you can determine whether $x$ is positive, negative, or zero; but you cannot determine the value of $y$, because there are in general two points on either side of the $x$-axis that will have the same signal arrival times.  In order to pinpoint the transmitter's location, you need a third receiver that is not collinear with the other two.